# Obtaining fee amount before completing an implicit payment

Tags: php, paypal

Is it possible to get the PayPal fee amount before completing an implicit payment through the classic API's?  On my website users will initiate implicit payments from my PayPal account to theirs and they will pay the fees.  I would like to display the fee amount and have them accept this before completing the transation.

Thanks!

Comment: Not too sure if the API has support for this, but I don't see why you could not calculate the PayPal fees server side, display them to the user, and add them to the total?

You should be able to find how much fees are by logging into your PayPal account. Depending on the account, they are a fixed rate or percentage.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yeah currently this is the way I am doing it however I am concerned about miscalculating when say for example the fee's change due to my previous months usage.